# How to manually assign colours in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

Because of the way my data is structured I need to create a plot like the below:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_point(data = dataset1, mapping = aes(x = time, y = estimate, colour = "label1")) +
  geom_line(data = dataset1, mapping = aes(x = time, y = estimate, colour = "label1"), size = 0.5, alpha = 2) +
  geom_point(data = dataset2, mapping = aes(x = time, y = estimate, colour = "label2")) +
  geom_line(data = dataset2, mapping = aes(x = time, y = estimate, colour = "label2"), size = 0.5, alpha = 2) +
  geom_point(data = dataset3, mapping = aes(x = time, y = estimate, colour = "label3")) +
  geom_line(data = dataset3, mapping = aes(x = time, y = estimate, colour = "label3"), size = 0.5, alpha = 2) +
  geom_point(data = dataset4, mapping = aes(x = time, y = estimate, colour = "label4")) +
  geom_line(data = dataset4, mapping = aes(x = time, y = estimate, colour = "label4"), size = 0.5, alpha = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("darkmagenta","paleturquoise4","lightpink4","gold"))
```

How can I be sure to set `"darkmagenta"` to `colour = "label1"`, `"paleturquoise4"` to to `colour = "label2"`, `"lightpink4"` to to `colour = "label3"` and `"gold"` to to `colour = "label4"`. Right now I don't understand how R is assigning the colours, it is not according to the sequence from dark magenta to gold.

Comment: Color is assigned by the order you provide in your values vector.

Comment: Thanks @TarJae I thought that would be the case, and so darkmagenta would be assigned to dataset1 (label1), and paleturquoise4 to dataset2 (label2) and so on... but that is not the case. Am I missing something?

Comment: create a  factor with the desired levels in order, this can be the reason when now the order is alphabetically. So if the order now is: "darkmagenta","gold","lightpink4","paleturquoise4" -> create a factor and relevel or level in order. Providing dput(head()) of your dataset would be helpful to solve.

Comment: You can also set the names within `values=`, as in `scale_color_manual(values=c(label1="darkmagenta",label2="paleturquoise4",...))`.

Comment: Thanks both, I didn't know about the option that @r2evans highlighted, it works!

Comment: Any reason you can't go the standard route of combining your data first? Like `mtcars1 <- mtcars[1:4,]; mtcars2 <- mtcars[5:10,]; mtcars_combo <- dplyr::bind_rows(d1 = mtcars1, d2 = mtcars2, .id = "id")`